# Wicket palette Available list issue

Tags: wicket, palette

We have a Wicket-based laboratory app, & followed the palette example shown here:

[Palette example](http://examples7x.wicket.apache.org/compref/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.source.SourcesPage?1&SourcesPage_class=org.apache.wicket.examples.compref.Index&source=PalettePage.java)

Initially, we have items with description = "pH", "pH1" and "pH2" on the Available list.

If we move "pH1" and "pH2" to the Selected list and save it, "pH" will no longer show up on the Available list.

If we change the item's description from "pH" to "PH", it shows up again.

Here's part of the code:

```
private List<LabMethod> availableMethods = new ArrayList<LabMethod>();
private List<LabMethod> selectedMethods = new ArrayList<LabMethod>();
....

//Get all the methods
availableMethods = labMethodService.getLabMethods();
//Get the methods for this user
if (user.getId()!=null)
    selectedMethods = lookupService.getMethodsForUser(user);
else
    selectedMethods = Collections.emptyList();

IChoiceRenderer<LabMethod> renderer = new ChoiceRenderer<LabMethod>("description", "description");

final Palette<LabMethod> palette = 
    new Palette<LabMethod>("methodPalette", 
    new ListModel<LabMethod>(selectedMethods), 
    new CollectionModel<LabMethod>(availableMethods), 
    renderer, 10, true);

palette.add(new DefaultTheme());
```

Comment: Its hard to tell what the problem could be without seeing your code as there could be a number of different causes. Seeing how you construct the palette (particularly its model and the choice renderer) would be very helpful for a start.

Comment: Thanks I've added some code.

Comment: Once pH disappears, if you move pH1 and pH2 back to available and save, does pH stay gone?

Comment: No - it's back on the list then.

Comment: I've also tried this with just 2 items "ABCD" and "ABCDE".
If "ABCDE" is on Selected then "ABCD" won't be on Available.

Comment: Could you also add the code to your LabMethod class? I feel like I know what the problem might be and that would could confirm it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems to be a regression introduced in Wicket 7.x - Palette doesn't support option ids containing each other:

E.g. when "AAAA" is selected from choices {"AA", "AAA" and "AAAA"}, Recorder#getUnselectedList() will return all as being selected (since all are 'contained' in "AAAA").